# Separating behaviour into two controllers which act on a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a Reservation model, my users with *student* role can create reservations online.
I have added the ability for a user with an *instructor* role to create reservations offline.

The controller actions *new*, and *create* are quite different for these two flows. The associated view template also has a number of differences.

I had considered using an if role==instructor check in the controller and view to allow me to cover both flows with a single controller. But I don't really like that approach.

---

So instead, I then made a separate controller and template for offline_reservations.
This worked ok, but I was having problems using CanCan to control access to it, since both controllers use the same Reservation model.

I did make one other change, I moved the new controller into a namespace,
so now it is located at

```
/offline/reservations/new
```

instead of

```
/offline_reservations/new
```

But I am not sure if that is an improvement or not.

Can someone advise what the best way to handle this scenario is?

1. I have two distinct sets of behaviour for a single model. How do I keep them separate. I don't really want them both in one controller, but if that is best then so be it.
2. Since there is a single model, I need to get CanCan to allow me to restrict access to each type of controller, but I am finding that difficult since they both use the same model
3. Is the user of a namespaced controller good/bad in this case..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorizing Namespaced and Nested controllers using CanCan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334367/authorizing-namespaced-and-nested-controllers-using-cancan)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the answer to my problem.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace